# Multiple channels in a single SSH session

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys, openssh, ssh-tunnel

I am debugging OpenSSH code where it seems multiple channels have been allocated on single SSH session (single connected child server).

My queries could be naive here:

> 1. Under what conditions can multiple channels be opened?
> 2. What are the SSH message flows which lead to multiple channels? A message flow chart will be very helpful.
> 3. Is it correct to free channels[0] in the case below?

```
(gdb) p channels[0]
$1 = (Channel *) 0xb0f33e20
(gdb) p channels[0]->rfd
$2 = 0xd
(gdb) p channels[0]->efd
$3 = 0xffffffff
(gdb) p channels[0]->wfd
$4 = 0xffffffff
(gdb) p channels[1]->wfd
$5 = 0x9
(gdb) p channels[1]->efd
$6 = 0xffffffff
(gdb) p channels[1]->rfd
$7 = 0x9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Under what conditions can multiple channels be opened?

Every channel is either X11 forwarding, TCP port forwarding (there might be more types), UNIX domain socket forwarding (or `ssh-agent` socket) or MUX proxy. Consulting [source code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/channels.h#L42) describing the types is a good start. They are opened, if the client requests them using command-line options (`-X`, `-L`, `-R`, `-D`, `-A`, ...) which are described in the manual page for `ssh`.

> What are the SSH message flows which lead to multiple channels? A message flow chart will be very helpful.

If you will run the OpenSSH client and/or server in debug mode (`LogLevel DEBUG3`), you will get a lot of useful information what messages are being exchanged for various use cases.

> Is it correct to free channels[0] in the case below?

Most probably not, but it is not clear what you ask here and what is the context. That is obviously valid channel with read file descriptor pointing to FD `0x0D` so you might expect there will be something to read at some point.

Comment: The channel can also (and usually is) be a shell (or exec=command).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl yes. From user point of view it is mostly perceived that way, but the channels code does not have any sense of shell or commands. It just redirects data from one way to the other.